# numpy.random.multinomial at version 1.16.6 is 10x faster than later version

Tags: numpy, performance, multinomial

Here are codes and result:

```
python -c "import numpy as np; from timeit import timeit; print('numpy version {}: {:.1f} seconds'.format(np.__version__, timeit('np.random.multinomial(1, [0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4])', number=1000000, globals=globals())))"
```

```
numpy version 1.16.6:  1.5 seconds # 10x faster
numpy version 1.18.1: 15.5 seconds
numpy version 1.19.0: 17.4 seconds
numpy version 1.21.4: 15.1 seconds
```

It is noted that with fixed random seed, the output are the same with different numpy version

```
python -c "import numpy as np; np.random.seed(0); print(np.__version__); print(np.random.multinomial(1, [0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4], size=10000))" /tmp/tt
```

Any advice on why numpy version after 1.16.6 is 10x slower?

We have upgraded pandas to latest version 1.3.4, which needs numpy version after 1.16.6

Comment: Does the changelog reveal anything?

Comment: I filled [this issue](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/20636) to get some feedback from the Numpy team and ask if they could improve the situation.

Answer (score 3):

**TL;DR:** this is a [local performance regression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_regression) caused by the overhead of **additional checks** in the `numpy.random.multinomial` function. *Very small arrays* are strongly impacted due to the relative execution time of the required checks.

---

### Under the hood

A binary search on the Git commits of the [Numpy code](https://github.com/numpy/numpy) shows that the performance regression appear the first time in mid April 2019. It can be reproduced in the commit `dd77ce3cb` but not `7e8e19f9a`. There are some build issues for the commit in-between, but with some quick fix we can show that the commit `0f3dd0650` is the first to cause the issue. The commit says that it:

> Extend multinomial to allow broadcasting 
> Fix zipf changes missed in NumPy 
> Enable 0 as valid input for hypergeometric

A deeper analysis of [this commit](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/commit/0f3dd0650) shows that it modifies the `multinomial` function defined in Cython file `mtrand.pyx` to perform two additional following checks:

```py
def multinomial(self, np.npy_intp n, object pvals, size=None):
    cdef np.npy_intp d, i, sz, offset
    cdef np.ndarray parr, mnarr
    cdef double *pix
    cdef int64_t *mnix
    cdef int64_t ni

    d = len(pvals)
    parr = <np.ndarray>np.PyArray_FROM_OTF(pvals, np.NPY_DOUBLE, np.NPY_ALIGNED)
    pix = <double*>np.PyArray_DATA(parr)
    check_array_constraint(parr, 'pvals', CONS_BOUNDED_0_1)   # <==========[HERE]
    if kahan_sum(pix, d-1) > (1.0 + 1e-12):
        raise ValueError("sum(pvals[:-1]) > 1.0")

    if size is None:
        shape = (d,)
    else:
        try:
            shape = (operator.index(size), d)
        except:
            shape = tuple(size) + (d,)

    multin = np.zeros(shape, dtype=np.int64)
    mnarr = <np.ndarray>multin
    mnix = <int64_t*>np.PyArray_DATA(mnarr)
    sz = np.PyArray_SIZE(mnarr)
    ni = n
    check_constraint(ni, 'n', CONS_NON_NEGATIVE)              # <==========[HERE]
    offset = 0
    with self.lock, nogil:
        for i in range(sz // d):
            random_multinomial(self._brng, ni, &mnix[offset], pix, d, self._binomial)
            offset += d

    return multin
```

These two checks are required for the code to be **robust**. However, they are currently *pretty expensive considering their purpose*.

Indeed, on my machine, the first check is responsible for ~75% of the overhead and the second for ~20%. The checks takes few micro-seconds but since your input is very small, the overhead is huge compared to the computation time.

---

One workaround to fix this issue is to write a specific Numba function for this since your input array is very small. On my machine, `np.random.multinomial` in a trivial Numba function results in good performance.

Answer (score 2):

I checked some generators that are under the hood and saw no much change in the timings.

I guessed difference may be due to some overhead, because you are sampling only single value. And it seems to be good hypothesis. When I increased size of the generated random samples to 1000, difference between 1.16.6 and 1.19.2 (my current Numpy version) diminished to ~20%.

```
python -c "import numpy as np; from timeit import timeit; print('numpy version {}: {:.1f} seconds'.format(np.__version__, timeit('np.random.
multinomial(1, [0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4], size=1000)', number=10000, globals=globals())))"
```

```
numpy version 1.16.6: 1.1 seconds
numpy version 1.19.2: 1.3 seconds
```

Note that **both** versions have this overhead, just newer version has it much larger. In both versions it is much faster to sample 1000 values once than sample 1 value 1000 times.

They changed by much the code between 1.16.6 and 1.17.0, see for example [this commit](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/commit/17e0070df93f4262908f884dca4b08cb7d0bba7f), it's hard to analyse. Sorry that can't help you better - I propose to make an issue on Numpy's github.

Comment: Version 1.17.0 is where the new API was introduced, which may have something to do with it. Do you know if `np.random.default_rng().multinomial` has the same overhead?

Comment: @MadPhysicist Yes, this is even much slower. Moving `np.random.default_rng()` to inizialization helps, but still this has same/bit worse performance